# Class 'Mongo' not found in XAMPP 64-Bit Windows 10

Tags: php, mongodb, apache, xampp

I'm trying to run the following code from on my localhost:

```
<?php

  $dbhost = 'localhost';
  $dbname = 'phpTest';

  $m = new Mongo("mongodb://$dbhost");
  $db = $m->$dbname;

?>
```

And get the error, "Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\key_ratios\mongo_test.php on line 6"

[MongoDB is properly installed/recognized by PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqwXo.png)

I've restarted Apache several times and MongoDB is running as a service. Mongo's directory path is C:\mongodb\bin. PHP is in C:\xampp\php.

The following are PATH variables: C:\xampp\php, C:\mongodb\bin, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin, C:\Users[redacted]\AppData\Local\atom\bin.

Any idea why I can't get PHP to connect to Mongo?

Edit: I should note that my mongodb listingin phpinfo() is not nearly as filled out as [this one](http://www.virtualsecrets.com/misc_imgs/linux/mongo-driver-php-installed.jpg). Does this mean my mongodb isn't fully installed?

Comment: Please have a read of https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/ and then pick the currently supported and maintained driver/API combo. By enabling the mongodb extension you've handled the driver part; but it does not provide `class Mongo`. Now you can either use the [driver interface](http://docs.php.net/mongodb) directly or put a more convient api/library in front of it.

Comment: So basically all I have to do is successfully install this file via composer https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library ?

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong syntax to connect. Should be (with PHPLIB):

`new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");`

or (with just the PECL driver): `new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");`

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php) is really helpful.